# Collect comments of Facebook pages and groups not owned without an app for data science project

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For my school project for graduation, I need to collect comments and posts from Facebook groups and pages to do sentiment analysis on them. 
Please note that I don't own any of thoses groups or pages. 
As far as my understanding goes, I need an access page token for every single page and group and I need to submit an app for review. Since it's a data science project, I don't have an app to submit for review. What can I do to collect comments and posts without an app? 
I hope my questions are not stupid, I've been searching for answers to this for weeks, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"without an App" - not possible and not allowed. Facebook specifically forbids scraping.

You can use an App Token though, with Page Public Content Access: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Keep in mind that you have to get your App reviewed for that. Afaik there is no way to get comments/posts of Groups without managing the Group though. Check out the requirements: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#readperms

> The app must be installed on the Group.

(which is only possible as admin)

You would definitely have to go through Review too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#groups-4-4

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! So for my use case, there is no way to collect the data since there is no app involved?

Comment: An app just means you need to go to developers.facebook.com and click a button. But then you need to get it approved for Page Public Content Access which is extremely unlikely. I would suggest doing something else

Comment: Ok one last question please, what if I'm a moderator of the page, will I need to submit an app for review too? Thank you.

Comment: in that case, you can try with a page token